# Which thread is invoking the line?

Tags: java, multithreading

I am trying to learn about threads and this got me thinking.
Please tae a look at the following -

```
public static void main(String [] args) {  // line 1
   Thread exampleThread = new Thread() {   // line 2
      public void run() {                  // line 3
         //some code                       // line 4
         ...........                       // line 5
         ...........                       // line 6
      }                                    // line 7
   };                                      // line 8
                                           // line 9
   // Which thread invokes this line?      // line 10
   exampleThread.start();                  // line 11
                                           // line 12
   // Which thread invokes this line?      // line 13
   exampleThread.join();                   // line 14
}                                          // line 15
```

I think **main** thread invokes **line 11**.

But what about **line 14**? Which thread is invoking it? **Main** or **exampleThread**? Can you please explain?

Comment: Both are by the same 'calling' thread. The calling thread  starts the exampleThread, and by calling join will wait for it to finish - you're blocking the calling thread until exampleThread completes. You could print the system time before you start the thread, then in your example Thread logic sleep for 2 seconds, then at the end print the time out again, you should see the calling thread blocked for 2 seconds, rather than returning immediately becaise join was called.

Answer (score 1):

The `exampleThread.join()` is also invoked by the main thread.

What it does is block the calling thread (the main thread here) until the other thread (`exampleThread`) has completed.

In general, a sequence of instructions is always executed by the same thread. There is no way another thread can jump in and take over (but it is possible that multiple threads run the same sequence of instruction at the same time, even on the same object instance).